# Pulando entre aplicações remotas usando o cordova (problema complexo)

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, mobile

Olá,

Tenho 3 aplicações e que cada uma se encontra disponível para iOS e Android e gostava de criar uma app para aceder a todas elas.

Para conseguir isso preciso pegar o código de cada uma das aplicações e movê-lo para um servidor de modo a que esta quarta aplicação possa fazer um redirect entre as apps.

É importante mencionar que cada uma das aplicações precisa aceder aos controlos nativos do phonegap e como tal precisa de ter importado no source code o ficheiro cordova.js ou phonegap.js

Acontece que quando compilamos uma aplicação esse ficheiro é injectado no directório de acordo com a plataforma para a qual estamos a compilar.

Ao mover as aplicações para diferentes servidores surgem alguns problemas que se devem a estes simples requisitos funcionais:

- A aplicação local permite abrir aplicações remotas
- As aplicações remotas conseguem aceder aos controlos do aparelho e aos plugins nele instalados
- A partir de qualquer aplicação remota deve ser possível regressar à aplicação local

Problemas:
- As minhas aplicações remotas estão alojadas no seu próprio domínio tais como a.com, b.com, c.com. Todas as aplicações comunicam com uma api que se encontra no dominio d.com. Como o administrador não pode autorizar o CORS, quando abro a aplicação no InAppBrowser as aplicações não conseguem comunicar com a API, pois o dominio da aplicação que estamos a aceder é diferente do dominio da api (ex: A.com != c.com logo => Temos CORS). Tipicamente, este problema não existe se pegarmos no código que se encontra em qualquer uma dessas aplicações: ("a.com"... "c.com") e a compilarmos porque as aplicações deixam de estar alojadas num servidor.

- Posto isto, e sem resolver o problema de como ter acesso aos controlos da aplicação surge-me a ideia de colocar diferentes versões da aplicação no servidor em que cada uma delas faz host do ficheiro phonegap.js para a plataforma que fez o pedido.

Exemplo: Ao abrir a aplicação 4 a aplicação detecta que estamos a usar um android e vai criar links dinâmicos que me permitem ao projecto que tem no seu directório o phonegap.js para androids.

por outras palavras: 
a.com/android <---- possui um phonegap.js para androids
a.com/ios <---- possui um phonegap.js para ios

Mesmo que esta solução funcione continuo sem saber como voltar a aplicação local.

Alguém tem ideias que possam ajudar a resolver estes problemas?
Espero não ter sido muito confuso, o problema é complexo

Answer (score 2):

Realmente o problema é bem complexo, na verdade ficou até um pouco confuso. 
Porém acredito que tenha atendido a sua pergunta.

Você possui diversas aplicações para `iOS` e `Android`, você deseja criar uma forma de integração entre as aplicações, por isso desenvolveu uma nova aplicação remota a fim de alternar entre as aplicações locais (ou instaladas nos dispositivos).

O primeiro ponto que devo levantar é em relação ao seguinte:

> Para conseguir isso preciso pegar o código de cada uma das aplicações e movê-lo para um servidor de modo a que esta quarta aplicação possa fazer um redirect entre as apps.

Não exatamente, você deve adaptar uma aplicação (ou portar) para que ela funcione em um **Servidor**, para isso você pode utilizar a linguagem que desejar, o ponto é que em algum momento nesta aplicação dentro do Servidor você devera fazer chamadas as aplicações dentro dos dispositivos. Para isso você pode utilizar **URI Schemas**, existe até Plugins já prontos para Cordova:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

Cabe citar que existe muita gente que não recomenda definir URI Scheme já que vai contra os padrões, mais informações neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430045/how-to-register-some-url-namespace-myapp-app-start-for-accessing-your-progr/2430468#2430468), porém com isto você consegue enviar informações entre uma aplicações no servidor.

Se você está fazendo uma aplicação com o Cordova e apenas colocando os arquivos (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) em um servidor e chamando eles no Cordova, talvez você deva repensar sua estratégia, além dos inúmeros problemas que isso pode causar, como falta de compatibilidade e arquivos quebrados. O que você deve fazer é criar uma aplicação que apenas requisite os dados (ou mesmo as páginas completas) de um servidor, porém a aplicação tenha autonomia para validar/verificar os dados e informar erros (falta de conexão, arquivos quebrados).

Sobre o problema do **CORS**, se o administrador do servidor não autoriza CORS, a melhor solução seria trocar de servidor, existe formas de "bypass" utilizando um proxy das requisições em outro servidor com outras tecnologias, porém se o problema mesmo é o administrador não permitindo, ele provavelmente também irá bloquear qualquer outra alternativa.

Sobre sua ideia de tornar os JavaScript locais para o domínio alterando a requisição do mesmo e evitando o uso de CORS. Você realmente pode fazer o Cordova identificar a plataforma e fornecer o melhor arquivo para ela, porém não é a melhor solução, você está tornando o problema que já é complexo em algo mais complexo ainda e adicionado mais riscos de problemas com compatibilidade de versões.

Do meu ponto de vista a melhor estratégia é criar um WebService apenas para trocar as informações entre os aplicativos locais. Nada de requisições de arquivos JS ou qualquer outro formato, apenas dados. E dentro de cada aplicação aconteceria o tratamento das informações, verificações de versões dos dispositivos, chamadas para outros aplicativos e/ou telas. A fim de centralizar seus dados em um único local e manter aplicações diferentes em seus próprios escopo.

Se não entendi sua pergunta, ou me confundi em algo, por favor desconsidere.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta henrique. Irei verificar com atenção as suas sugestões e volto para dar feedback